# How to copy standard output and standard error to the log?

Tags: bash, shell-script, logs, exec

I need to write the standard err and standard output to `$LOG`, while also having them printed on console, from within a script.

The script has many commands, so redirecting each one of them is not a good solution.

I've tried this, but it didn't work as expected:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG=/var/tmp/log

#...

exec > $LOG  2>&1
```

My target is to write to `$LOG` on any standard output and standard error,
but on the same time also to the standard output (on console). Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [tee](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tee-invocation.html). For example:

```
command 2>&1 | tee file.txt
```

Which runs `command` redirecting SDTERR to SDTOUT. `tee` copies STDIN to both STDOUT and to file `file.txt`.

In bash you can use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) in following way to copy output to `$LOG`:

```
exec &> >(tee $LOG)
```

However this *bashism* **won't work** on other shells.

Comment: I dont want to add to each command tee -a I have around 200 commands in  my script , my target is to change the "exec > $LOG  2>&1" in order to support also printing on the console

Comment: Updated answer with bash process substitution example.

Comment: exec > >(tee $LOG) , in the bash - on the end of the script , script not return cursor

Comment: Works as expected, tested it with `exec > >(tee output.txt)` and `cat` command https://pastebin.com/M93MEzKe .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the most clean solution but it worked for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG=/var/tmp/log

(
# lots of commands
# ...

) 2>&1 | tee $LOG
```

@sebasth gave a better solution, though:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG=/var/tmp/log

exec &> >(tee $LOG)

#...
```